# AngularJS: $parsers vs $validators

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS both $parsers and $validators can be used to validate forms. I was wondering what exactly the difference is between using a $parser and using a $validator.

Let's look at the following example:

**Validation using a parser**

```
angular.module("myFormApp")
    .directive("containsWhiteSpace", containsWhiteSpace);

function containsWhiteSpace () {

    function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
        return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
    }

    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl){

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                if(value){
                    var isValid = !hasWhiteSpace(value);
                    ctrl.$setValidity('hasWhiteSpace', isValid);
                }

                return isValid ? value : undefined;
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**Validation using a validator**

```
angular.module("myFormApp")
    .directive("containsWhiteSpace", containsWhiteSpace);

function containsWhiteSpace () {

    function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
        return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
    }

    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl){
            ctrl.$validators.hasWhiteSpace = function(value){
                return !hasWhiteSpace(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

They both do the same thing, but when is it correct to use a parser and when is it correct to use a validator? What are the advantages of both? What are the differences?

Comment: $validators was only introduced in 1.3+ whereas if you use < 1.2 then you use $parsers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$parsers` are run in a pipeline, to transform the input value. They can return `undefined` if they fail to parse the input, indicating a parse error. If the input value fails to parse, the validators are not run.

`$validators` are run after parsers, on the parsed value. They can return `false` to indicate a data error.

Basically

- use parsers to coerce a string input value into the data type you need/expect.
- use validators to validate a value of the correct data type.

For example, consider a model requiring a positive number. `$parsers` can call `parseFloat` on the value, and `$validators` can check if the value is positive.

For the example you gave, I think `$validators` are more appropriate (and cleaner).

Comment: What if I want when I clear the field the model to be set back to `undefined` without my parser to be considered invalid? How do I achieve that?